# How can I fake a cookie in a web request that's generated dynamically?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, cookies

I need to get some public data from a link, but this is a second time I encounter a Cookie that I cannot replicate as some values in it are dynamic. How can I get this cookie before doing an actual request to get my data?

Example link:

```
https://www.blackrock.com/ca/individual/en/products/239832/ishares-sptsx-60-index-etf/1464253357804.ajax?tab=chart
```

Example headers:

```
Host: www.blackrock.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://www.blackrock.com/ca/individual/en/products/239832/ishares-sptsx-60-index-etf
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSION_amer-retail01=EA5A098E120F4E3FAD2C994A64F292E4.03; ts-ca-one-locale=en_CA; FIRSTPAGE_ca_ca-one=page-class-home; blkUserType-ca-one=individual; ipe_s=0d9c807a-04cc-ae5b-e459-d89bddd2faab; ca-one-recent-funds=239832; __utmt=1; __utma=17023466.874636303.1499433731.1499433731.1499433731.1; __utmb=17023466.5.10.1499433731; __utmc=17023466; __utmz=17023466.1499433731.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmgclid=CJjax_ah99QCFZxMDQodKQ4NxQ|utmgclsrc=aw.ds|utmccn=(not%20set)|utmcmd=(not%20set)|utmctr=(not%20provided); _bizo_bzid=0688d0c2-d203-488b-b128-94c0406b5568; _bizo_cksm=B16C1965883E71EB; _bizo_np_stats=14%3D243%2C; ipe.20668.pageViewedCount=3; utag_main=v_id:015d1d3702f6001b054da00951140407300ad06b00bd0$_sn:1$_ss:0$_pn:6%3Bexp-session$_st:1499436924463$ses_id:1499433730806%3Bexp-session; s_pers=%20s_fid%3D5295C92DBD9DC781-0177F2F787EC9066%7C1562507124793%3B%20gpv%3Dca-one%257Cca%257Cfund%257Cishares%2520s%2526p%252Ftsx%252060%2520index%2520etf%257Cxiu%7C1499436924795%3B%20s_nr%3D1499435124796-New%7C1530971124796%3B%20s_pers_eVar17%3Dprospect%7C1502027124797%3B%20s_pers_prop19%3Danonymous%7C1502027124799%3B; s_sess=%20s_campaign%3Dppc%253Ablackrock_ca%253Agoogle%253Ablackrock%3B%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B; s_vi=[CS]v1|2CAFC5818507C33B-6000011540002202[CE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a [CookieContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) and set it to the [CookieContainer property of your HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx). Then make an initial request and after you `GetResponse` the cookie container will be populated with any cookies returned.

Then reuse the `CookieContainer` in subsequent requests and all the previous returned cookies will be sent.